# socket.io send jwt via cookie

Tags: javascript, node.js, cookies, socket.io

I am trying to use jwt for authentication. Right now I use socket-jwt for this task. I store the jwt in localStorage. But for my other http requests(ex: fetch), I authenticate using passport and cookie. I want to do the same(send token via cookie) with socket.io. Is there a way to send a jwt to socke.io for authentication?

below is my current codes.

```
//server side
io.use(socketioJwt.authorize({

  secret: config.secret,
  handshake: true
}));

//client side
var socket = io({query: 'token='+localStorage.getItem("token")}).connect();
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I solved it this way, but whitout Passport (Socke.io v2.1.0):

> WS Server (excerpt)

```
import io = require('socket.io');

sioServer = new io(httpServer)

sioServer.of(namespace).use((socket, next)=>{

wsTokenVerify(socket, next);

})
```

> wsTokenVerify(socket, next)

```
    async  wsTokenVerify(_socket:Socket, _next: NextFunction) {

    let cookie = _socket.request.headers.cookie
    let token = parsCookie(cookie);
     try{
         decodedJWT= await jwt.verify(token,this.RSA_PUBLIC_KEY,{ 
          algorithms: ['RS256']});
      } catch(err){
            sendJsonResponse(_res, 401, err);

         }
        _next();
    }
```

hope it helps